# Google e-Commerce tracking doesn't track

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-api, tracking

I tried to test google e-commerce tracking locally and I have put this code in my order `finalize.aspx` page

But when I go to google analytics profile - I see that one user is checking the site but none of my products are added to the reporrting of e-commerce

What may be the problem?

```
<title>Receipt for your clothing purchase from Acme Clothing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-68062306-1', 'none');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        ga('require', 'ecommerce');
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
            'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
            'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
            'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
        });
        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
            'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
            'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
            'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
            'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
            'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
            'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
        });
        ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Comment: Did you remember to wait - (e-commerce) data will show up with several hours (up to a day) delay.

Comment: Yes probably that's the reason :) can i see with the debugger that everything is Ok

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics v4 - Data not showing on dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867128/google-analytics-v4-data-not-showing-on-dashboard)